# Azure API call not getting logged

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I'm new to Azure but had good exposure to AWS. I've trying to understand audit logging in Azure. I've called List By ResourceGroup API using my credentials, I got a 200 Ok response with the storage accounts in my RG but this was not logged in Azure Monitor activity log. Could you please help in understanding where this event gets logged? Been trying since 3 hours but couldn't find the log entry anywhere. Am I looking at the wrong place?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/list-by-resource-group

Answer (score 0):

The [Activity Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log?tabs=powershell) record events such as resource creation, updates, and deletion, as well as control-plane operations performed by Azure Resource Manager.

However, it is important to note that not all REST API calls generate activity log events. For example, some service-level APIs bypass the Azure Resource Management layer and are not logged. Instead of List, use Create or Delete API call instead.